# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' while trying to reading a json file using pd.read_json

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, attributeerror

The error message says:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-fdd8ab51df81> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 
      4 filename = "/content/CapybaraPure_Decontaminated.jsonl"
----> 5 instruction_dataset_df = pd.read_json(filename, lines=True, orient='split')
      6 examples = instruction_dataset_df.to_dict()
      7 

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1324             decoded = {
   1325                 str(k): v
-> 1326                 for k, v in loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float).items()
   1327             }
   1328             self.check_keys_split(decoded)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I am trying to read json files using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "/content/CapybaraPure_Decontaminated.jsonl"
instruction_dataset_df = pd.read_json(filename, lines=True, orient='split')
examples = instruction_dataset_df.to_dict()
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  I'm not sure you have described it correctly.

Comment: hi there @davinci can you provide the json file of yours, its possible that the error maybe caused by wrong data structure in the json file.

Comment: @TimRoberts How do I share the file ?

Comment: I'm saying just cut-and-paste the first few lines and add it to your question.